# Flash AS3: Cursor hand not display in Firefox

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, button

I have the code below adding a movie clip to my stage and setting the buttonMode to true. I can see the cursor hand in Chrome but not in Firefox. I do not have any text inside of this movie clip. Any ideas?

```
//get the objects
var mcLogo:mc_logo_still = new mc_logo_still();

mcLogo.buttonMode = true;

//add the still object to the stage
addChild(mcLogo);
var mcLogo_X = 142.00;
var mcLogo_Y = 66.00;
mcLogo.x = mcLogo_X;
mcLogo.y = mcLogo_Y;


//set up the link
function gotoHomePage(event:MouseEvent):void {
    //var targetURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://mc.com/");
    //navigateToURL(targetURL);
    navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://mc.com"), "_blank");
}

mcLogo.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoHomePage);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you're using Firefox 4.0. There seems to be a bug in Firefox 4.0 regarding Flash and mouse-cursor (also affects `Mouse.hide()`). Apparently there's nothing you can do about it for now... Also have a look at this [Firefox help thread](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/questions/796828).

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug with Firefox. It was introduced in Firefox 4 and was not addressed in Firefox 5. "useHandCursor" will not fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Add these two lines after the button mode line :

```
mcLogo.useHandCursor = true;
mcLogo.mouseChildren = false;
```

Comment: didn't seem to work. Is there any particular order these lines need to be?

Comment: I edited the answer and added a line, as I don't know the composition of the mcLogo. What version of firefox do you have ? Also, what version of the flash player do you have in firefox ?  If possible can you put a link to the .swf so I can check it in firefox.

Comment: yeah - may just wanna make sure no other stage element is covering the clip. Ideally, if the clip contains other clips, you should put a button in the clip specifically to carry out any click actions too.

Comment: also, if the parent of the clip has mouseChildren = false, that could also cause something like this. But, I'm doubting that since it works in chrome, and it's just firefox that has this behavior.